# How to remove waiting time in python? (Selenium??)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My program is a simple selenium project that just opens and clicks a button. But in the beginning it needs to open multiple browser instances since if I use multiple tabs the website will kick me out. The code is:

```
        driver = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver2 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver3 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver4 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver5 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver6 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver7 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver8 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver9 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        driver10 = Edge(executable_path=BASE_DIR + r"\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
        print(Fore.GREEN)
        driver.get(template)
        print("1st line connected")
        driver2.get(template)
        print("2nd line connected")
        driver3.get(template)
        print("3rd line connected")
        driver4.get(template)
        print("4th line connected")
        driver5.get(template)
        print("5th line connected")
        driver6.get(template)
        print("6th line connected")
        driver7.get(template)
        print("7th line connected")
        driver8.get(template)
        print("8th line connected")
        driver9.get(template)
        print("9th line connected")
        driver10.get(template)
        print("10th line connected")
```

yes so I just want it to be able to do all of that at the same time without waiting for the previous connection to be finished. In selenium it works like when the first driver finishes the next driver will connect. But I want it to connect them all at the exact same time.

Comment: Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is likely gonna help you. I've used it in the past to run multiple instances of a scraper with different options.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it